# Can Kubernetes use mirrors by default to allow for an offline network cluster setup?

Tags: kubernetes, nexus, containerd

I'm currently working with Kubernetes and my end goal is to transition my cluster into an offline network. In this context, I have a question that I'm hoping someone might be able to help me with.

Is it possible to set up Kubernetes in a way where it can use mirrors by default? I am using containerd as runtime and I would like to know if and how this configuration could be feasible. I will be using Nexus for the repo.

Could anyone provide some guidance on whether this is possible, and if so, what steps I would need to take?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling container images isn't actually implemented by Kubernetes, it just sends the request to the CRI plugin. Containerd [does support this though](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/cri/registry.md).

```
version = 2

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
      endpoint = ["https://internal-mirror"]
```

and then similar for each remote registry you want to redirect.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have already tried that and it seems that containerd doesn't recognize my mirror.However, when I run the command, I still don't see any changes.
```
sudo ctr images pull docker.io/library/alpine:latest
...
ctr: failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/alpine:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/alpine/manifests/latest": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:41874->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

Comment: my config
`
version = 2

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
      endpoint = ["http://repo.labo.bi:8082/"]
`